# "No dereference" option when touching symlinks with GNU Make

Tags: makefile, timestamp, symlink

GNU Make has a `-t` flag to update the timestamp of target files as if they had been rebuilt. Some of my targets are symlinks, and I want GNU Make to update the timestamp of the symlink, not the referenced file.

- GNU Make has the `-L|--check-symlink-times` option to *read* timestamps from symlinks instead of their referenced files, so it's at least aware of a related issue.
- The `touch` command has the `-h|--no-dereference` flag which is exactly the behavior I'm looking for.

But is it possible to invoke this kind of behavior while running `make -t`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the [make source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/remake.c#n1145) makes it look like you can't do this.

The `touch_file` function linked above is the function that I believe does the timestamp updating in question and it just uses `open` to open and update the file.

```
      int fd = open (file->name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);
```